# BigQuery read-only with a pre-set budget

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

is it in Google Cloud Platform possible to create a user with read only Access to a BigQuery Table and moreover a pre-set Budget ? I have a new colleague and he never worked before with BigQuery and i want to avoid a high bill at the end of month.

Thx

Answer (score 1):

You can set, not for a specific user, but for all the users, a quotas that limit the too high cost expenses. You have details [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/custom-quotas)

If you want to enforce this quotas to only this user, create a project dedicated to this user, grant them as bigquery job user (to allow them to create query jobs), and bigquery data viewer on the table/dataset that you want (to allow them to access to the data to request). on this specific project set the quotas that you want. Like that, only the user that use this project to query BigQuery will be limited by the quota.